# cryptsetup: bad password or options?

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, cryptsetup

With a fully encrypted disk, the OS is Ubuntu 20.04, just after powering up the computer, the boot prompts for the disk encryption password in the middle of the screen with one single field.

I have two questions:

- if I enter a wrong password, it says: "cryptsetup: Bad password or options?". What are the options that I can pass in the field in the middle of the screen and how do I pass such option? I'm not talking about a cryptsetup command line in a terminal, I'm talking about the password field in the middle of the screen during boot. How do you enter any option?
- After 3 failed attempts, the system forces me to wait for 30 seconds before trying again. Is there a simple "sleep" in the initramfs script/kernel or is there a much more complex mechanism to avoid a brute dictionary attack? It's not like I'm going to type a whole dictionary in a tiny boot prompt.

Comment: What's your distro and version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is the distro